# Javascript Append a new Jquery file with noconflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append a new version of jquery into head section as below.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>

    <script>
    $jq(document).ready(function() {
        // works well
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

It works fine when I put it directly. But my case is, I need to append it dynamically, reslove noconflict and the implementation using external javascript file (my.js). (As below)

my.js file should be consisted with the all implementation.

```
    // insert jquery file
    var jqueryfile = document.createElement('script');
    jqueryfile.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    jqueryfile.async = true; 
    jqueryfile.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(jqueryfile, s);
```

How to do my implementation with jQuery.noConflict() and $jq(document).ready(function() {}).

Thank you!

Comment: what is use case that you need another version loaded?

Comment: hi @charlietfl, I just edited my question. the use is, im going to include my js file in external website and there i will do some client side implementations. my implementation are written by jquery, so i need to jquery be to be there.

Comment: can cause problems with user code calling `noConflict` if user has jQuery code that loads into page after you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to insert script in HEAD section

```
head1=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
var s1 = document.createElement("script");
s1.type = "text/javascript";
s1.innerHTML="var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$jq(document).ready(function() {
    // works well
});
";

head1.appendChild(s);
head1.appendChild(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need to include a regular js file in the regular fashion like so and alias jQuery as a parameter, freeing up the dollar sign:

```
<script type="text/javascript">js/scripts.js</script>
```

and then add this to your scripts.js file:

```
;(function ( $ ) {

    // all code in this anonymous function will not conflict with any other library
    // and it will never get in to the global namespace which is good


    $(document).ready(function() {

       // works well
    });
})( jQuery );
```

now you can just use the "$" for jQuery freely

Comment: Hi @kkemple, you haven't understood my problem correct. never mind. thank you!

Comment: It's fine but you never said it was going to be imbed able script. You really shouldn't pull that much code in to someone's page you should do a check for j query and if not found warn them your script needs it. What you are attempting to do is bad practice